# How to prove $(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow(r\rightarrow s)$?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

Suppose $p,q,r,$ and $s$ are specific statements (arrow means implication).

If I'm asked to prove that $(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow(r\rightarrow s)$ for those specific $p, q, r,$ and $s,$ how would I set up a proof of that?

Where should we start with and how does natural direction algorithm or truth table shed light on the proof strategies? (or to simplify the statement)

Comment: The statement you give is not true in general.

Comment: There is one question that need to show one implication implies another. How should we start writing the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that $p, q, r,$ and $s$ here represent specific statements that you haven't spelled out for us, and that you're asking how to try to organize a proof of $(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow(r\rightarrow s).$

Typically one would think of this in the equivalent form

$$\big((p\rightarrow q)\wedge r\big)\rightarrow s.$$

One would then assume both  $p \rightarrow q$ and $r$ as given, and try to prove $s.$

Alternatively, for a proof by contradiction, you could assume the three statements $\;p \rightarrow q,$ $\;r,\;$ and $\;\lnot s,$ and derive a contradiction.

Comment: But how do you derive this equivalent form?

Comment: You can use truth tables to show that they're equivalent.

Comment: Truth tables is too slow. I'm thinking of quicker ways like sequent calculus

Comment: You can show first that $t\rightarrow(r\rightarrow s)$ is equivalent to $(t\wedge r)\rightarrow s,$ using truth tables, or a formal proof (using sequents or whatever), or simply by working out what it means for each side to be false and seeing that they're the same.  Then substitute $p\rightarrow q$ in place of $t.$